# bitbucket webook Permission denied

Tags: php, bitbucket

I created a php file to run git pull when there is a git push. added it to bitbucket webook.

But Im running into permission issue. I checked the Owner/Group of my /var/www/html/ is root root. and the /var/www/html/.git/ is also root root.
I am running ubuntu 14.04 and apache2

Error Log:

> error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Webhook file:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('git pull');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you `git clone` as user `root`?

Comment: yes git clone as root